# Naming convention between two pins Input -> Output

Tags: schematics

Is there some naming convention to name a net label (or hierarchical/global label) from an output to an input pin?

E.g. in the example below, for the name SHIFT_REGISTER_1_OUT, I could also use the following names:

- SHIFT_REGISTER_2_IN
- SHIFT_REGISTER_1_TO_2

Is there some kind of naming convention for such names?

[image]

Comment: @Andyakak Thanks ... (I cannot accept a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually give a name that applies to the output signal because it is dominant and, the input has no play in how that signal is created or changes. You should also try and give the signal a name that is more applicable to what it represents and not what IC generated it so "SHIFT_REGISTER_1_OUT" is a poor name because it is meaningless.

If that pin is the really representing an input from say a tacho or microphone then it should have a name that encapsulates the original source meaning (if you can).

But, at the end of the day, it's up to you and nobody's going to get bent out of shape whatever you call it.

Comment: I will think of a better name, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a formalised public convention, although at some places I have worked we had overall net naming conventions. The only rule for an actual name was 'be consistent and make the name descriptive enough so the purpose of the signal is immediately clear'.

As a couple of examples, when naming the nets on the path of a serial port (which came to / from the processor and out via a RS232 level shifter, using the sequence:

**Transmit** Proc_232_1_TX ->RS232 level shifter -> RS232_1_TX was deemed completely acceptable (in this cases, the '1' denoted the channel. 0 was discouraged as non programmers might be a bit confused).

**Receive** RS232_1_RX -> level shifter -> Proc_232_1_RX

Note that the transmit and receive are symmetric in the naming apart from the actual function (TX or RX).

In your case I might name the signal as S1_OUT_TO_S2_IN but the only rule is clarity.

I view net naming as a (very) effective form of variable naming (such as I would use in software) and also a great help when routing nets (in many tools the net name is visible on screen).

We did mandate the use of _p and _n suffixes in differential pairs (for both clarity and tool reasons - the tool cold then automatically figure out differential pairs) and it is a naming convention I heartily recommend (I had a design that had, on the backplane, 1152 full duplex multigigabit differential pairs for a total of 2304 pairs and proper naming saved a lot of hair and possibly my sanity).

So do whatever is *clear*; look at these names the same as variables in software - 'if you go back to the design in 6 months, would the purpose of the signal still be clear?' is the question I ask myself. If you can honestly answer yes to that then it is an effective naming convention.

Comment: Thanks ... I'm used to software variable naming, so I should find a good name. Thanks for the examples and explanation.